# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 with difference mvc version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, dll, ef-code-first

My MVC 4 project(use System.Web.Mvc.DLL version 4) was working,but now suddenly I get an error(without anything).That error occurs in my controller which call EF code first code from data layer

This is the line causing the error in MVC 4 Project:

```
var cultures = db.Cultures.Select(c => c.Code).ToArray();//call from data layer
```

In my mvc project I have deleted the data layer and added it again it again and then I set that DLL copy local to true but the error was not fixed.

My MVC project use System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0 and copy local is true And Data layer use System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 and copy local is true

I looked error inner exception it give that error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: Why are you adding MVC to your data layer? Your data layer should not know about what middleware you are using and just serve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your Web.config file? You should have a dependentAssembly defined for System.Web.Mvc  that specifies its version.